# Track docker repositories pull

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I searched for this, but couldn't get any answer. Is it possible to track (locations) of docker repositories pull ?

I have a docker repo and would like to know who is pulling it to work with, think of it like google analytics for docker images

Is that possible to do through the docker hub ?

Thanks

Comment: Put the repository behind a proxy like Nginx or Apache (lots of examples online). Both those web servers have access logs that track requests, recording the originating IP address

Comment: smart, yes I can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Hub does not provide that information right now. I've got it filed internally as a feature request, "ST-1961".

As of November 2017, this feature has not been implemented.

-- Andy Rothfusz, Docker Support Manager (2012-2015)

Comment: Thank you Andy, are your tickets publicly available ? (public Jira ? )

Comment: Sorry, no. The Docker Hub isn't open source, so we don't have an open source bug tracker. I've given the issue ID here so that people can ask for a status update in the future and we'll know where to look. Folks with Hub accounts are welcome to file issues and feature requests on support.docker.com.

Comment: @Andy been a while... is there any update on this? Is this now a supported feature by any chance?

Comment: @gsaslis, sorry, I left Docker in 2015 and I don't think this feature has been implemented. I see some recent forum activity at https://forums.docker.com/c/general-discussions/feature-requests so maybe one of the current Docker team could help there.